# Multiple ssl hosts on nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have multiple ssl sites on one server with nginx, and the virtual hosting works like this:

```
root /var/www/html/$host;
```

But in the certificate section, the `$host` variable doesn't work:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/$host.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/$host.key;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just use different config files. If you insist on using just one, Use a symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt `ssl_certificate` can be parametrized - it's parsed when `nginx` is started, so the process must know it's filename to perform OpenSSL initialization process, but in case of parametrized vhosts this is just not possible - `server_name` isn't known.

You have to create non-parametrized vhost configuration files for SSL, or use wildcard certificates (for example **.foo.bar*) ***and*** semi-parametrized vhosts, like `server_name *.foo.bar;`.